# Stop power query from loading to excel sheet

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am currently learning Power Query in Excel. I have a spreadsheet full of historical sales data, which contains dates and sales. For each month, I create a new spreadsheet to analyze sales data. In each monthly spreadsheet, I have a "setup" sheet, where I put in the month start and end dates, and defined names "from_date" and "to_date" (my months are not based on actual month start and end).

Therefore, in Power Query, I have set up a query that selects all of the sales data, which is then filtered based on two blank queries from the two named dates. This works well, but it loads these "blank ranges" into the excel sheet. Is it possible to stop this from happening, and only keep the two named date queries in Power Query?

Comment: You have not provided enough detail to answer your question. Maybe you can edit your question to post an image of your source data, post an image of what current output looks like, post an image of what you would like the output to look like, and post the code you are using in Powerquery so far (found in home ... advanced editor)

Comment: You can just delete the worksheets created by PowerQuery. If you open the Queries & Connections pane from the Data ribbon, you'll see that the query should now say Connection only. Alternatively, when you first click Load To, you can choose the Only Create Connection option.

Comment: Thanks, Bryan, that is what I am looking for. Many thanks.